# Excel VBA Macro Find/Cut/Paste

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a difficult time coming up with a solution for a project I'm working on. I am needing a Macro to look at a specific sheet, find a specific value, and cut/paste that value at the end of the row.

Looking at the example file I have attached, you can see that each customer has a unique ID in column A.

They are answering a questionnaire, and each answer they give generates a unique ID.

The order of the answer ID's doesn't matter, as they are unique. The only one that DOES matter is the answer with Semicolons. That answer ID needs to be the customer's last ID. So I need to find a way to cut these answer ID's and paste them to the end of each row.

I want the semi-colon answer to be the last answer in the array. First time posting on here so I'm sorry if the format is incorrect.

Updated: Example File

[image: IMG1]

Comment: I'm not understanding the format the data is currently in...

Comment: Is there a way for me to upload an example file?

Comment: so what in the world is `;0;2,0;3,0;4,0 ...`

Comment: That is a new answer ID. Its just vastly different that the previous ones we have worked with. we are currently having issues because this is a CSV file I am trying to generate, and they want this last answer to be separated by semi-colons. It is all one answer ID though. That entire string

Comment: Honestly I think you need to rewrite a good chunk of the question and [give us an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the input and the expected output for a few rows

Comment: You are right. I re-worded the question and included an example file. Let me know if this is easier to understand.

Comment: is it okay if the cell where the semicolon used to be is just left blank after it gets moved to the bottom?

Comment: Yes, that is perfectly fine. We tested the upload and the file uploads fine if there is a blank in the middle.

Comment: StackOverflow is *not* a free coding service, so please, include your efforts...

Comment: Thanks JohnyL. I appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this will do what you're looking for. It goes through columns and loops through each row in those columns and once it finds a cell with a `;`, it just moves that value down to the bottom of the row it was found in.

```
Sub AnswerID()

    Dim lastCol As Long
    lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To lastCol

        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.count, i).End(xlUp).row

        Dim j As Long
        For j = 1 To lastRow
            If InStr(Cells(j, i), ";") > 0 Then
                Cells(lastRow, i).offset(1, 0).Value2 = Cells(j, i).Value2
                Cells(j, i).Value2 = vbNullString

                Exit For
            End If
        Next j

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: @SKIPPYSxHOPPIN Good to hear :)